# How to compress a Pdf file in Windows 8 and Windows 7

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file of 9mb but I want to convert it into less than 1mb.How can I do that? I have used all the online tools available.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you produced it with, what level of PDF compliance you set, what target purpose / amount of images.

1. What you made it with: Some design software (Ilustrator) gives the option to leave editing information in the PDF. You would want to switch anything like that off.
2. Level of PDF compliance - compression got better with higher PDF versions. Go for the highest level you can.
3. Target purpose / content: Target purpose means DPI. Re-sample the images to the appropriate size for the output purpose. If you are for example intending the PDF to be displayed on a phone or tablet, then you do not need those massive images that you took with your 24Gb SLR.

Acrobat Pro tends to be good at compressing and removing junk.

9Mb is quite large for a PDF so I assume it is full of rich images. Reducing the size and colour depth of those images is likely to be the biggest benefit.